# Play your role the best

Tags: adverbs

Is the following sentence correct

> In an imperfect world with not-so-perfect people and institutions, you have to play your role **the best** you can, take as many as you can along with you, with empathy and a bit of loving detachment

When **best** is used as adverb, it is not preceded by **the**.

Example

He works best in the morning.

So I think **the** should not be used before **best** in the above sentence.

Am I right?

Comment: It's fine to say **do the best you can** but the usual expression is to do something **as best you can**. While it's correct to say **He works best...** without the article, to omit **the** in your first example is wrong unless you say **...your role as best you can**. https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/best       https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/as-best-you-can

Answer (score -1):

You are correct, the sentence is not written properly. It would be more correct to say **as best** in this case.

*However*, this is an extremely common usage, despite being incorrect. Interactions with native English speakers and writers (at least those used to the U.S. style of English) will likely feature this kind of error often.